# How to stop clearing browser console code history?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, console

I am using the chrome browser console and i want that my javascript code that i have typed in the console once, would be executed every time when the browser is going to a different page, no matter if the browser was closed before or the computer has restarted. Is there a way to stop the console of clearing history code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Console does not serve that purpose. Better use [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=pl) extension.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i have tryed the extension and it works. But i am still thinking is there a way from javascript code without the extension to save the code forever in the console? for example "if the path of the page is reloading then return this javascript code" or something else.. Could this be possible?

Comment: As I said before, console doesn't serve that purpose. You should use console only if you want to test something once.